# Sql Server Error Caused by Web Part

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, web-parts

I am using webparts to create a dashboard page. To do that i am dynamically loading the webparts.

```
strZoneNumber = "zone" + intCnt.ToString();
UserControl UC = (UserControl)LoadControl(row["c_widget_path"].ToString());//Loads the usercontrol
UC.ID = row["c_widget_webid"].ToString();
UC.Attributes.Add("Title", row["c_widget_webid"].ToString());
//UC.Attributes.Add("title" , "Test");
GenericWebPart ucwebPart = wpmDashBoardManager.CreateWebPart(UC);//creates a webpart
wpmDashBoardManager.AddWebPart(ucwebPart, wpmDashBoardManager.Zones[strZoneNumber], ZoneIndex);//adds it to a zone
wpmDashBoardManager.Zones[strZoneNumber].Visible = true;
```

My webpartmanager personalization mode is set to 'true'

While running this page on the server it is giving me the following error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> SQLExpress database file auto-creation error: 
>   The connection string specifies a local Sql Server Express instance using a database location within the applications App_Data directory.
>    The provider attempted to automatically create the application services database because the provider determined that the database does not exist. The following configuration requirements are necessary to successfully check for existence of the application services database and automatically create the application services database:

If the applications App_Data directory does not already exist, the web server account must have read and write access to the applications directory. This is necessary because the web server account will automatically create the App_Data directory if it does not already exist.

If the applications App_Data directory already exists, the web server account only requires read and write access to the applications App_Data directory. This is necessary because the web server account will attempt to verify that the Sql Server Express database already exists within the applications App_Data directory. Revoking read access on the App_Data directory from the web server account will prevent the provider from correctly determining if the Sql Server Express database already exists. This will cause an error when the provider attempts to create a duplicate of an already existing database. Write access is required because the web server accounts credentials are used when creating the new database.

Sql Server Express must be installed on the machine.
The process identity for the web server account must have a local user profile. See the readme document for details on how to create a local user profile for both machine and domain accounts.**

Any ideas as to what might be causing this and solutions? Help would be greatly appreciated :):)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many features of ASP.NET rely on intrinsic application services such as membership, roles, profiles, and personalization. For example, the ASP.NET personalization service uses a personalization provider to save personalized user settings on Web pages. By default Web Parts try to save personalizations into SQL Express database.

This solution was helpfull for me.

In connectionStrings section of your web.config file remove LocalSqlServer connection and add it again with your own preferences:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <remove name="LocalSqlServer"/>
    <add name="LocalSqlServer" connectionString="yourConnectionString" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Then if you will have 'Could not find stored procedure 'dbo.aspnet_CheckSchemaVersion' error  you should create a new database for you to use for personalization.
So, just explore `C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_regsql.exe` and go through steps of the wizard.

Hope it will help.