# Stuck at Error : A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I am getting this error not in all pages of website but in only one page.
I can't found any solution,

**Error**

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

I have referred to this link

[Similar Question from stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18060667/why-am-i-getting-cannot-connect-to-server-a-network-related-or-instance-speci)

But problem still persists.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, then **please show us** your connection string that is being used on those "one page" in your web site!

Answer (score 0):

So you are saying that there's a problem with only one web page? maybe some other class is used to retrieve the backing data? Maybe you should compare it to the other pages? Basically if the problem doesn't appear on other pages, then SQL Server is configured properly.

It's really hard to help you if you don't share anything from your code. It surely touches your connection string, so maybe you should first compare the one used on this faulty web page to the other ones (from the pages where you don't get any error).

Comment: Actually i have used web part in my page which causing problem,and as you suggested, i have checked both pages both are using same connection string,but problem was with of web part.Its a webpart personlization problem

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I have used web part in my page which causing problem, so problem was with web part. It was a web part Personalization problem. For now, I have keep `Personalization-Enabled="false"`.

[Similar Question from stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8061097/sql-server-error-caused-by-web-part)